# How can I upload 10 screenshots to AppStore?

Tags: app-store, screenshot

I just can upload 5 screenshots on ApsStore.
But I can see some apps with 10 screenshots.
I don't know how to do that.
Is there anyone knowing about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 5 for iPhone, 5 for iPad if your application is "Universal"

Comment: I hadn't noticed that there were only five screenshots in AppStore. I saw 10 screenshot apps on a app-searching app. In the app,  universal apps have 10 screenshots as you said. Thank you!